# Exchange 2007 and 2013 can't send email internally to eachother

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, sccm-2007

We have exchange 2007 installed with all roles installed on that server. 
Now we want to Migratie exchange 2013 and we installed exchange server 2013 with all roles on another server. After that I wanted to test the mailflow internally between the 2 exchange servers, but the users from exchange 2007 can't send emails to the exchange 2013 users and the other way around.  Any suggestions what is causing this issue?

Kind regards,

Litrick

Comment: Please tell us what you have already tried and what error messages (if any) you have gotten.

Comment: There was a ASA firewall between the two subnets (any, any) but I had to Disable ESMTP Inspection on the Cisco ASA. Now the mailflow works

Comment: @Litrick please change your comment to an answer on your own question.  Then accept that answer when it lets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a ASA firewall between the two subnets (any, any) but I had to Disable ESMTP Inspection on the Cisco ASA. Now the mailflow works